# Summernote uncaught type error

Tags: jquery, summernote

I am using Summernote 0.87 with jQuery 2.24 - it all works absolutely fine with no issues. I now need to add image upload and it "doesn't work".

Since I first used Summernote, the console has been constantly filled with messages about uncaught type error - they haven't caused any issues before but I need to fix them before I can look at what might be wrong with image upload. The errors are like the below:

```
jquery.js:3749 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery224087811350551713432' of undefined
    at Data.get (jquery.js:3749)
    at Data.access (jquery.js:3768)
    at Function.data (jquery.js:3906)
    at HTMLDivElement.b (jquery.validate.min.js:4)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4737)
    at HTMLFormElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4549)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.js:7807)
    at Object.simulate (jquery.js:7866)
    at HTMLDocument.handler (jquery.js:7925)
```

jQuery224087811350551713432 changes to a seemingly random value each time - I cannot find any specific dependency on the jQuery version and, whilst I can find lots of similar topics for property replace I cannot find anything similar to this.

I cannot upgrade to jQuery 3 as Bootstrap JS requires less than jQuery 3 so I am hoping this is not a version issue.

Can anyone help with this error?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in https://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Not the same error - I get some errors which do not appear in my live code about tooltip and unexpected tokens but not that specific error

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery noconflict mode?